# Matrix representation of the $x$-component of orbital angular momentum $\hat{L}_x$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, observables, spherical-harmonics

In my notes it is given that using the spherical harmonic (shown below) as basis states in this order, the matrix representing the $x$-component of orbital angular momentum $\hat{L}_x$ for a particle with angular momentum quantum number $l=1$:

$$
\qquad
\hat L_x=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}} \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \tag{1}
$$

The spherical harmonic used are:

> [image: Blockquote]

I am trying to derive the matrix of $\hat{L}_x$.

First I need to find the eigenvlaues and eigenvectors of $\hat{L}_x$, however I cannot find it anywhere and I don't know how to derive it.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive $L_x$ from the ladder operators $L_{\pm}$.

These operators verify:
\begin{equation}
L_{\pm} | 1, m \rangle= \hbar \sqrt{2 - m (m \pm 1)} | 1, m \pm 1 \rangle
\end{equation}

With the given basis you can derive the matrix for these operators and find $L_x$ like:

\begin{equation}
L_x = \frac{1}{2} (L_+ + L_-)
\end{equation}

Comment: would you able to give me the general equation for $L^+$ and $L^-$ rather than for $l=1$

Comment: Sure. In the general case the first term inside the square root is $l(l+1)$. You can easily see how the "2" for $l=1$ arises. You can check all of this at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator